# Placing variable out of list into string (url code)

Tags: python, string

my list looks like:

```
lst
['78251'],
 ['18261'],
 ['435921'],
 ['74252'],
 ...]
```

I want to place that numbers into a url code
http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::SectionDataSet,rma::criteria,[failed$eq%27false%27],products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27],genes[entrez_id$eq%27**inhere**%27]'

I tried

```
for i in lst:
    b = 'http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::SectionDataSet,rma::criteria,[failed$eq%27false%27],products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27],genes[entrez_id$eq%27%d%27]' %i
```

I get no error message but it says

```
b
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-79-89e6c98d9288>", line 1, in <module>
    b

NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

So I think the difficult part is that there is no space in between the string... How can I handle this?

Comment: The error is caused by a `b` in your code. There is no `b` variable in what you've included. It seems you've entered a `b` and pressed enter from your error message.

Comment: Oh sorry I changed the code.. I tried to safe the url in b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is complex, but see example URL:

```
a= 'http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=' + i + '&gene=model:' + i
```

Comment: Oh I tried this but I forgot a second +.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this much more pythonic approach, using .format():

```
for i in lst:
    b = "http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::SectionDataSet,rma::criteria,[failed$eq%27false%27],products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27],genes[entrez_id$eq%27{}%27]".format(i[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [["78251"], ["18261"], ["435921"], ["74252"]]
for val, in lst:
    b = "http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::SectionDataSet," \
        "rma::criteria,[failed$eq%27false%27],products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]," \
        f"genes[entrez_id$eq%27{val}%27]"
```

Directly access to values of interest with `val, in lst` and use implicit string concatenation along with an f-string at the end to substitute the value.